# Standard Normal Distribution-Inequality

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, normal-distribution

Suppose that $\Phi(.)$ and $\phi(.)$ are the cdf and the pdf of the standard Normal distribution, respectively. Does the following inequality hold $\forall x>0$:
$$2x\phi(x)+2\Phi(x)-1\geq 0$$

Comment: Indeed it is, but i had to find a partial derivative which was about 3 pages in order to make it in an appropriate form and this was the only easy part (that i missed after all :P), that I was not sure for the sign...Now i can say that the whole derivative is positive and that's all! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For $x>0$ we have $\Phi(x)>\frac12$, hence 
$$2\Phi(x)-1 \geq 0 $$
and since $x\phi(x)$ is positive for positive $x$ it clearly holds.

Comment: Thank you very much!